# React-Native Error - "[TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2._OnAlert(count)')]"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I am trying to build a sample app which pops up an alert displaying the number of objects in the response of an API. The alert pops up once but afterwards, I am getting this error

```
[TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2._OnAlert(count)')]
```

This is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Button, Alert } from 'react-native';
import ProductListingItem from './ProductListingItem';

export default class ProductDetailedListingPage extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

 }

 _OnAlert(count){
    console.log('_onAlert');
    console.log('count = '+ count);
    Alert.alert(
      'API call success',
      count+' objects',
      [
        {text:'done',onPress: () => { }}
      ]
    );
  }

 _getResponseFromApi(){
    console.log('_getREsponseFromApi called');
    var myRequest = new Request('http://mysampleapi.com:8082/listProducts',);
    myRequest.method = 'GET';
    return fetch(myRequest)
      .then((response)=> response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        var data = responseJson.error;
        console.log('data = '+data);
        /*console.log(responseJson);*/
        var count = Object.keys(responseJson).length;
         count = '2';
         console.log('count in _getResponseFromApi = '+count);
        this._OnAlert(count);
        return responseJson;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

 componentDidMount () {
    console.log('componentDidMount');
    this._getResponseFromApi();
  }
  componentWillMount () {
    console.log('componentWillMount');
  }

 render(){
    console.log('render');
    return(
      <View style = {{
        flex:1,
        flexDirection:'column',
      }}>
      <Button style ={{flex:1}}
        onPress ={this._getResponseFromApi}
        title ="Call"
        />

     </View>
    );
  }
}
```

The problem is with `_OnAlert()` , it runs for the first time at `componentDidMount()` without issues and displays the alert dialog, but at the instance of `onPress()` it gives me the above mentioned error. I am a noob when it comes to React and Javascript, especially JSX. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Remove `bind()` from `this._OnAlert(count).bind()`

Comment: Tried that ,, now the error is [TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating '_this2._OnAlert(count)')]

Comment: I am changing it in the question also, just in case.

Comment: Change `onPress ={this._getResponseFromApi}` to `onPress ={this._getResponseFromApi.bind(this)}` or add `this._getResponseFromApi=this._getResponseFromApi.bind(this)` to constructor.

Comment: Cool, that is also working. Just out of curiosity, why does the `OnAlert` work when it is being called from `componentDidMount()` ?? Also, why doesn't binding `OnAlert()` to `this` work??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your constructor and bind the method '_getResponseFromApi' to the scope here,

```
constructor() {
super();
  this._getResponseFromApi = this._getResponseFromApi.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks,, that worked perfectly.. Can you tell me what was causing that error and what exactly that fix did to fix it ? Thanks a lot, I had been sitting on this for a long time.

Comment: Actually we are setting the scope on which the function has to be executed by using bind() method.  So 'this' is the keyword which holds the scope of entire class.  So to access anything from that scope, you need access to that scope(which was done by .bind(this))

Comment: From what I understood, when the method is called from a button click, it becomes a Function call, hence we have to bind the method so that the pointer remains intact. Whereas when calling the method from `componentWillMount()', it works as a regular method call..